# Reproducing Heinrich Heidersberger's Rhythmograms

Tags: plotting, graphics, random, generative-art

Heinrich Heidersberger  (1906 - 2006) was born in Ingolstadt, Germany, and grew up in
Austria. He studied architecture in Graz, which he abandoned in favor of art. From 1928 until 1931 he lived in Paris and studied painting at Fernand Leger’s École Moderne. There he became friends with many Surrealists.

Rather accidentally he bought his first camera at the flea market and
in the coming years devoted himself more and more to photography. As early as the
end of the 1940’s he published his first reportages, among others for the
LIFE magazine. In 1961 he moved to Wolfsburg. There he documented the life of the fast-growing industrial city. The photographs taken during this time are counted among the icons of German post-war-modernity.

[image]

*Heinrich Heidersberger, Volkswagen factory, Wolfsburg 1971*

Heidersberger also produced mathematical drawings using a self-constructed photographic machine. Four pendula move a point of light during a long exposure time creating complex images of light tracings. Heidersberger himself called these photographs "Rhythmograms" and his apparatus a "Pendelmaschine" or pendulum machine, later a "Rhythmograph". Today, these drawings can be found in international museums, among others in the Museum of Modern Art, New York.

[image]

*Heinrich Heidersberger operating his Rhythmograph, 1950s*

[image]

*Heinrich Heidersberger, Rhythmogram, 1955*

My attempt to reproduce a Rhythmogram was only partially successful, especially because I didn't find a way to alter the distances between lines (the black stripes in the above image).

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[0.9 t] Cos[0.501 t], Sin[0.2 t + 1] Cos[0.4 t]}, {t, -340, 340},
 AspectRatio -> 1.25,
 Axes -> False,
 Background -> Black, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 120,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighter @ Gray, Thickness @ 0.0015]]
```

[image]

**My question**

Can we create a rhythmogram similar to the one below? More important for me than the overall form are the grid patterns "interrupted" by darker stripes of parallel line segments.

[image]

*Heinrich Heidersberger, Rhythmogram, 1955*

Here you can see more drawings: [heidersberger rhythmograms](https://www.heidersberger.de/pages/stories/rhythmogramme/subpages/ct_128/englisch.html?sprache=englisch)

Comment: (+1) I know that eventually I will see a book of yours on generative art using Mathematica. ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### A starting point

- We use two variables `{u,v}`: a parametric form of Mobius Strip `f[u,v]` and product with some factors to pertabation the surface.
- then we rotate it and project to 2D dimension.
- We `Drop` the `Mesh` to remove some meshs to get the darker stripe.

```
f[u_, v_] := {(1 + v/2    Cos[u/2])    Cos[
     u], (1 + v/2    Cos[u/2])    Sin[u], v/2    Sin[u/2]};
factors[u_, v_] := {Sin[u], 1, Cos[v]};
F[u_, v_] := f[u, v]*factors[u, v];
 vector = {-2, -3, -4};
ParametricPlot[
 RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1},vector }]@F[u, v] // Most // 
  Evaluate, {u, 0, 2   π}, {v, -1, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Drop[Subdivide[-1, 1, 50], {24, 25}]}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[White, AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
 Background -> Black, Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

### A general method

- The `pts` is from `Canvas[]`.(we use `pts[[1 ;; -1 ;; 40]]` to select some points)

```
Clear[pts];
pts={{0.341667, 0.737343}, {0.0353543, 0.729766}, {-0.0785346, 
  0.626988}, {-0.0674235, 0.503377}, {0.0075765, 0.407544}, {0.108965,
   0.279766}, {0.125632, 
  0.0964328}, {0.0214654, -0.121623}, {-0.0715902, -0.307734}, \
{-0.111868, -0.513289}, {0.0131321, -0.641067}, {0.204799, \
-0.654956}, {0.36591, -0.609123}, {0.393688, -0.491067}, {0.270076, \
-0.418845}, {0.0561876, -0.360512}, {-0.135479, -0.318845}, \
{-0.310479, -0.218845}, {-0.395201, -0.0605116}, {-0.289646, 
  0.136711}, {0.0117432, 0.333933}, {0.214521, 0.401988}, {0.350632, 
  0.426988}, {0.450632, 0.474211}, {0.461743, 0.6131}, {0.36591, 
  0.7256}};
```

- We use the idea of `Frenet-Serret` frame. That is we moving a segment line along a curve `f[s]`, both of the length of segment and the direction of such segment line is variety respect to the curve `f[s]`.

```
Clear[f];
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
ParametricPlot[
 f@s + {Normalize[f'[s]], Cross[Normalize[f'[s]]]} . {Cos[s/10], 
     Sin[s/10]}*t*Sin[s], {s, 0, 1}, {t, -1/2, 1/2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Drop[Subdivide[-1/2, 1/2, 50], {24, 25}]}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[White, AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
 Background -> Black, Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

- Use `ListInterpolation` to define the `angle` and `length` functions of the moving segment line along the `frame`.

```
Clear[f, frame, angle, length];
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
frame[s_] := {Normalize[f'[s]], Cross[Normalize[f'[s]]]};
angle = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[{-π, π}, 20], {{0, 1}}];
length = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[{0, 1}*1/2, 20], {{0, 1}}];
ParametricPlot[
 f@s + Dot[frame@s, AngleVector@angle@s]*length[s]*t, {s, 0, 
  1}, {t, -1, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Drop[Subdivide[-1/2, 1/2, 50], {24, 25}]}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[White, AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
 Background -> Black, Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you cvgmt, this far exceeds my expectations

Comment: @eldo  Thanks you question, it makes me review my knowledge about differential geometry many years ago.